# Insert new record to table without primary key (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to integrate PhpBB with CakePHP. And in PhpBB there is table phpbb_user_group without primary key:

```
group_id | user_id | group_leader | user_pending
```

When I'm creating new user I need to add new record to this table but CakePHP is giving me following error:

```
Cannot insert row in "phpbb_user_group" table, it has no primary key.
```

I could add column with primary key to the table but I would rather not. Updating PhpBB is always pain in the butt and I foresee problems in the future, so I prefer to not modify database structure.

Is it possible to insert new record to table without primary key in CakePHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to "manually" create and run `INSERT` statements, for example using the query builder, you won't be able to use the ORM's saving functionality, as it relies on primary keys being present.

```
$statement = $Table
    ->query()
    ->insert([
        'group_id',
        'user_id',
        'group_leader',
        'user_pending'
    ])
    ->values([
        'group_id' => $groupId,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'group_leader' => $groupLeader,
        'user_pending' => $userPending
    ])
    ->execute();

$success = $statement->rowCount() === 1;
$statement->closeCursor();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Inserting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Running Insert Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-insert-statements)**